# Separation of variables $x$ and $y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the numerical coefficient $n$ not included in the separation of the variables $x$ and $y$?

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = nxy\implies\dfrac{dy}{y} = nx\,dx.$

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean ? it's a constant. No matter if it's on the left side or right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerical coefficient (or constant) $n$ is included when you separate $x$ and $y$. It is a constant which appears inside the general solution for the first order differential equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = nxy\implies\frac{dy}{y} = nx\,dx \implies \ln |y|=\frac{nx^2}{2}+C \implies y=C\large{e^{(nx^2)/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Separation of the variables $x, y$ means that you obtain an equation without $y$ in the LHS and without $x$ in the RHS.

Comment: Or conversely, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work! Even $n$ is included or not included. But with a different values of the constant. For example,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2xy$

SOLUTION: $n$ IS INCLUDED

$\frac{dy}{2y} = xdx$

$\int{\frac{dy}{2y}} = \int{xdx}$

$\frac{1}{2} \int{\frac{dy}{y}} = \int{xdx}$

$\frac{1}{2} ln|y| = \frac{x^2}{2} + c$

$ln|y| - x^2 = 2c$

SOLUTION: $n$ IS NOT INCLUDED

$\frac{dy}{y} =2 xdx$

$\int{\frac{dy}{y}} = \int{2xdx}$

$\int{\frac{dy}{y}} = 2 \int{xdx}$

$ln|y| = 2 \frac{x^2}{2} + c$

$ln|y| - x^2= c$